# Difference between Picard-Lindelöf and Peano's Existence

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Peano's existence theorem is as follows:

> If: $$(t_0, y_0)\in \mathbb{R^2},\quad R = {\{(t, y) : |t-t_0|\leq a, |y-y_0|\leq b}\}$$ $$F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad cts.$$ $$|F(t, y)| \leq M, \quad M\in \mathbb{R}$$ $$a_* = min{\{a, \dfrac{b}{M}}\}$$
> Then, the system $y'(t) = F(t, y(t)), \quad y(t_0) = y_0$ has a unique solution $(t, y(t)): [t_0 - a_*, t_0 + a_*] \rightarrow [y_0 - a_*, y_0 + a_*] $.

Now, it seems that the only difference between this and the Picard-Lindelöf theorem is that the Picard-Lindelöf theorem requires such an $F$ to also be Lipschitz continuous, but it gives that such a solution $y$ must be unique. Is this the main difference or am I missing some big point?

Comment: As far as I know the theorem by Peano doesn't guarantee *uniqueness*. What's your source?

Comment: @Hyperplane https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem . It's also mentioned in baby Rudin (chapter 7 or 8 I believe)

Comment: "The solution need not be unique: one and the same initial value (x0,y0) may give rise to many different solutions z." is says right there on the page

Comment: OOPS SORRY I meant uniqueness of course!

Comment: Picard-Lindelof, technically, requires global continuity and Lipschitz continuity just in the second variable "uniformly with respect to the first one", meaning that $$\sup_t\sup_{y_1\ne y_2} \frac{\lVert F(t,y_1)-F(t,y_2)\rVert}{\lVert y_1-y_2\rVert}<+\infty$$ However, uniqueness is the main difference. Notice that the theorem you have stated says that the length of the interval where a solution is defined depends only on how big $\lvert F\rvert$ is in a neighbourhood of the initial point, and not on any parameter measuring its regularity (of course, this carries on to Picard-Lindelof).

Comment: @Hyperplane haha okay, there is the confusion. They both guarantee a solution, but only Picard-Lindelöf guarantees a *unique* solution.